# I moved my office for another place and changed my ip address, i can't connect to svn server anymore

Tags: svn

i'm using eclipse indigo, and i'm connecting to svn sever via vpn.

proxy autorisation to my ip address is ok, and i reached successfully the svn address by url in my browser

synchronizing svn failed, it shows changes in the outgoing mode, but never shows changes in incoming mode.

Comment: What errors do you receive?

Comment: Error Status 503, Service unavailable on checking for update

Comment: there is some problem on server side. Did you contact an admin?

Comment: yes he says that i'm allowed to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the active provider to Direct and it worked

[image]